# rails post request after_create model, suggestions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, post

I have a nested model after every create or update I would like to send a post request with the model to an external API.

Should I do this in my model?

Comment: this should be handled by the controller.  you can use `before_save` and have it send requests to your external api

Comment: I would argue in favour of an observer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I do this in my model?

No, you shouldn't be doing this in your models. Instead, use an [Observer](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Observer). They're specifically meant for watching for events in your model layer, and triggering some code which shouldn't live in your model layer:

> Observer classes respond to life cycle callbacks to implement trigger-like behavior outside the original class. This is a great way to reduce the clutter that normally comes when the model class is burdened with functionality that doesn’t pertain to the core responsibility of the class.

Comment: first time i've ever heard of an observer. +1